# Convert Colums Values Into Row result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry If this is duplicate...

I have this table (Id,Col1,Col2,..,Col3) but I want to have results grouped like this

```
ID1value group,
Col1Value,
Col2Value,
Col3Value

ID2value group,
ID2Col1Value,
ID2Col2Value,
ID2Col3Value

ID3value group,
ID3Col1Value,
ID3Col2Value,
ID3Col3Value
```

How to do it?
I have tried `PIVOT` but I think this does not return good result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want `UNPIVOT` as opposed to PIVOT:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, Col1 VARCHAR(15), Col2 VARCHAR(15), Col3 VARCHAR(15))
INSERT @T (ID, Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES
    (1, 'ID1Col1Value', 'ID1Col2Value', 'ID1Col3Value'),
    (2, 'ID2Col1Value', 'ID2Col2Value', 'ID2Col3Value'),
    (3, 'ID3Col1Value', 'ID3Col2Value', 'ID3Col3Value');

SELECT  upvt.ID,
        upvt.Value
FROM    @T
        UNPIVOT
        (   Value
            FOR [Group] IN ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3])
        ) AS upvt;
```

Giving:

```
+----+--------------+
| ID |      Value   |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | ID1Col1Value |
| 1  | ID1Col2Value |
| 1  | ID1Col3Value |
| 2  | ID2Col1Value |
| 2  | ID2Col2Value |
| 2  | ID2Col3Value |
| 3  | ID3Col1Value |
| 3  | ID3Col2Value |
| 3  | ID3Col3Value |
+----+--------------+
```